# How to set correctly with Javascript a date value to an input date html field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i have a set with javascript a value to a input date field. The value displays well on screen but the form read the field as empty, i don't know why.

this is my JS code :

```
jQuery('#field_date_7171036551').val("2020-02-02");
```

You can test the code directy here : https://wp.mykitxenon.fr/?product=classic-wooden-chair

Take a look at the result :
[image]

Comment: Make sure that the format you're using for the date `("YYYY-MM-DD")` matches the expected format of the date input field. If the field is using a different format, you may need to convert your date to that format.

Comment: I think the format i used is ok, i checked that before.

Comment: What does the validation function look like?